# Syncing many microservices, single response to client

Tags: microservices, masstransit

How to sync an action of many microservices and return a single response to the client that takes into consideration each microservice's response?

I'm making a social network application (like Facebook) with microservices, for learning purposes. I've divided the app into following microservices, each will have its own database:

1. Authentication - Login/Register, returns a JWT token.
   Database stored properties are: UserName, Email, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt.
2. UserProfiles - Gets and Updates profiles.
   Database stored properties are: UserName, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Photos
3. UserPosts - user can publish Posts with anything he likes, others can comment.
   Database stored properties are: UserName, UserPosts, Comments
4. Gateway - collects http requests from clients, forwards them to correct microservices

THere will be more, like Messages between users.

Some properties in databases will duplicate (UserName, but there can be more). I suppose I cannot avoid that if I want to make the services independent.

Now, what do I do if the user decides to change a shared property, like UserName? Obviously it will require every service to update its database. But what if one of services cannot connect to the database or meets some other error? The response should be 500 Internal Server Error. I can see two options for that:

1. Make the Gateway send an HTTP request to each microservice, requesting an update. How do I pass  information about an error in one of the services? This seems a bad approach
2. Publish a message (MassTransit, RabbitMQ) to all microservices with update request. This way I can await a response from each service and decide what to return to client. But who should be the publisher here? Gateway? Authentication?

Is there some other way I have not thought about? I'll be thankful for any good-practice, clean-code advices.

Thank you

I tried messaging services from Authentication services, since it's the one that creates the User entity in the first place. But it doesn't feel like a good reason to make it there.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more research, I think I may have found a solution. I learnt about the Saga Orchestrator design pattern. Basically it's just a central unit of command, don't know what's all this fancy naming for. However, I will incorporate a central unit in the Gateway microservice. Then, it will still aggregate HTTP requests from clients, but instead of just redirecting them to appropriate microservices, it will send a message to each microservice involved, over AMQP protocol (with MassTransit, RabbitMQ or similar). It will await a response from each microservice and decide what to return to the client. If any service returns an error, I will request a rollback operation or retry.

Comment: Sample snippet could help

Answer (score 0):

To start off I would argue that such decomposition would be excessive for a real-world scenario. IMO microservices should evolve around [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) and all the social media stuff is a single bounded context. In case you wanted to introduce another one that is totally different (i.e. payment gateway) I would say that decomposition to microservices would make some sense. Although, even in such a case I would default to a [modular monolith](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd) since microservices are distributed systems and writing distributed system correctly is hard (which you might have already experienced).

Nevertheless, I recognize that the example you've brought up is solely for learning purposes. So to answer your question: most users are ready to tolerate some inconsistencies as long as they are warned about it. So the natural solution to your question is [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). In case you want to update Username you make a call to UserProfile microservice and if things are successful you return 200 response while sending `UsernameUpdated` message via RabbitMQ to other microservices. In such a case doing retries in case of failure would be a concern of every microservice that receives a message acknowledging the message once the update is successful.

As an alternative, you may call other microservices via RPC (HTTP) and wait for them to return a response in a synchronous fashion. But I suggest [avoiding that](https://wkalmar.github.io/post/make-synchronous-communication-short-lived/).

Regarding API Gateway it's a nice pattern in case you want a single entry-point for your client that routes requests to different microservices. Also, you can manage additional cross-cutting concerns like authorization in your API Gateway. But beware that every additional moving part adds complexity to your system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You suggest sending 200 response to the client and afterwards sending UsernameUpdated message via RabbitMQ to other microservices. This is the essence of my question. Shouldn't I rather wait for responses from all other microservices, in case one of them fails? And if one of them fails, shall I return 500 to the client and ask him to try later?

Comment: The essence of eventual consistency approach that I'm advocating is that you don't need to force user to wait until all of the microservices (and in real life, there can be many of them) perform the update. It's ok that not all the data is updated immediately. And you put the burden of resilience on the mechanisms inside your microservices instead of forcing user to constantly perform retries himself.